# How to make button open app settings after being clicked?

Tags: flutter

```
          body: Column(
    children: [
      Center(
          child: Text(
            string,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 54),
          )),
      TextButton(onPressed: (bool isOpened = await PermissionHandler().openAppSettings());
{   }, :const Text("check intrnet")),
 ],
     )
          );
```

I want to open AppSettings from the button being clicked

Answer (score 0):

**hey, I try to help your problem here.**

I just checked the package documentation,

I found this:

```
/// Opens the app settings page.
///
/// Returns [true] if the app settings page could be opened, otherwise [false].
Future<bool> openAppSettings() => _handler.openAppSettings();
```

here you can do with it :

```
Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Open App Settings'),
          onPressed: () async {
            await openAppSettings();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

You just need to call openAppSettings() function.